# How can I show table on next sheet based on current date?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lets suppose I have multiple tables on a sheet. Every table represents a month of a year. I want to show one of the tables, the table for current month, on the next sheet.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some specifics about the sheets' content and layout?  Any kind of specific answer will depend on what's there to work with.

Comment: Are these actually formatted as tables or just ranges of cells?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

Sheet1 contains a table like this:

```
Date......    First-column    ...
2012-01-01    Some text...    ...
2012-01-02    ...
....
```

Then Sheet2 with these entered:

```
A1: base    
B1: 2012-02-01
C1: =MATCH(B1;Sheet1!A2:A9999)  
A2: end
B2: =B1+(DATE(YEAR(B1);MONTH(B1)+1;DAY(B1))-B1)-1,=B2-B1
A3: =Sheet1!A1
B3: =Sheet1!B1
A4: =IF(ROWS($A$4:A4)<=($C$2);OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;$C$1+ROWS($A$4:A4)-2;COLUMNS($A$4:A4)-1);"")
```

... will display similar to (example second column as long version of date in first):

```
base        2012-02-12      43  < start row
end.        2012-03-11      28  < count
Date        dText       
2012-02-12  februari 12, 2012       
2012-02-13  februari 13, 2012       
2012-02-14  februari 14, 2012       
2012-02-15  februari 15, 2012       
2012-02-16  februari 16, 2012       
2012-02-17  februari 17, 2012       
2012-02-18  februari 18, 2012       
2012-02-19  februari 19, 2012       
2012-02-20  februari 20, 2012       
2012-02-21  februari 21, 2012       
2012-02-22  februari 22, 2012       
2012-02-23  februari 23, 2012       
2012-02-24  februari 24, 2012       
2012-02-25  februari 25, 2012       
2012-02-26  februari 26, 2012       
2012-02-27  februari 27, 2012       
2012-02-28  februari 28, 2012       
2012-02-29  februari 29, 2012       
2012-03-01  mars 1, 2012        
2012-03-02  mars 2, 2012        
2012-03-03  mars 3, 2012        
2012-03-04  mars 4, 2012        
2012-03-05  mars 5, 2012        
2012-03-06  mars 6, 2012        
2012-03-07  mars 7, 2012        
2012-03-08  mars 8, 2012        
2012-03-09  mars 9, 2012        
2012-03-10  mars 10, 2012
```

... assuming that you fill A4's content for the first two columns (in the example, expand at will), and have the shown data in Sheet1.

Change the "base" date and the display will adapt, using the day count in the month of the base date as line count.

'start row' is the row on the first sheet that match() finds with the base date as argument.

'count' is the day count in the month.

These are then used in the formula in A4 to pick out the relevant portion of the data with the help of OFFSET(), by counting ROWS() and COLUMNS().

Try to save this as "Test.csv" and open it in Excel, to get the formulas entered:

```
base,2012-02-02,=MATCH(B1;Sheet1!A2:A9999),"=""< start row"""
end,=B1+(DATE(YEAR(B1);MONTH(B1)+1;DAY(B1))-B1)-1,=B2-B1,"=""< count"""
=Sheet1!A1,=Sheet1!B1,,
"=IF(ROWS($A$4:A4)<=($C$2);OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;$C$1+ROWS($A$4:A4)-2;COLUMNS($A$4:A4)-1);"""")","=IF(ROWS($A$4:B4)<=($C$2);OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2;$C$1+ROWS($A$4:B4)-2;COLUMNS($A$4:B4)-1);"""")",,
```